# BHO with C++ Rest SDK (casablanca) - How to check the missing dependent DLLs?

Tags: c++, dll, bho, ieaddon

I have created a IE Add-on (Browser Helper Object) using unmanaged code (C++). I installed it on my machine and it works well without any issues. I tried installing it in another machine and it has this error.

> The module "IE-Addon.dll" failed to load.
>   Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files.
>   The specified module could not be found.

I believe that this error is cause by a missing dependent DLL as stated.
Is there any tool that can check a DLL and what are its dependents?

Comment: See if this helps http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: @Rao Thanks for the info. I already tried using it but couldn't figure out what went wrong. It said "At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found." I try to check what is it about on dependency walker documentation, it states that the entry-point to a module was never called since the operating system couldn't load all the required modules. Reference: [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/interpreting_errors.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the another info Jerry Coffin. I already checked on it so I changed the title of my question. I am currently using [casablanca]https://casablanca.codeplex.com. This is where the problem started the moment I use that library.

Comment: The is issue is resolved. I was using vc_redist 2013 while my development machine is in visual studio 2015. So using a vc_redist 2015 solves the issues. [Dependency Walker]http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/interpreting_errors.htm provided the determining factor of the issue. But because I am a first time user of it, I wasn't able to determine the missing DLL's.
Thanks all for additional information with regards to this issue.